# What do I do when my mech is destroyed?

Tags: overwatch

Playing as D.Va, my mech got destroyed with no progress towards getting a new one.

Since D.Va outside the mech has low health, no abilities, and a weak pistol attack, is it even worth trying to fight on foot? Is it ever better to just kill myself to get a new mech and, if so, when?

Comment: I don't think suiciding is ever the better strategy. D.Va's pilot ult charges pretty fast, and if nothing else, you're one more person acting as a distraction to everyone, *and* you have a tiny hitbox now.

Comment: I found out recently that her pistol is not semi-auto as I had assumed, but full auto. Just hold down the fire button and headshot that Tracer who thought you were going to be easy prey!

Comment: Also her pistol is really not that bad.

Comment: Her pistol is surprisingly strong and she builds ultimate ridiculously fast while dealing damage with it. You don't even need kills; spam into a cluster of enemies from a safe distance for a few minutes and you'll have a new mech before you know it.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish: "minutes"... lol xD And yeah I also have to add its dmg is suprisngly heavy!

Comment: @Zaibis Metaphorical minutes.

Comment: A related point you may not be aware of: D.Va has separate ult meters for mech and pilot. When she ejects, either due to damage or self-destruct, her mech ult charge is hidden and does not change until she's back in her mech (either by dying or calling a new one); her pilot ult charge is set to 0 and goes up in the usual way (except that it's *very* fast). If her self-destruct goes off and she's still alive in pilot form, her ult is *immediately* set to 100. This means you can use her ult as a sort of self-heal: assuming you survive the blast, you get a new mech at full health.

Comment: Another point: You can activate D.Va's ult *while* she's ejecting due to damage, forcing your assailants to flee and getting a new mech a few seconds later. This is obviously handy :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When your Mech is destroyed you run behind the rest of your team. You're weak, but your pistol does have some range to it. You should pepper the enemy team with shots (each shot SIGNIFICANTLY charges her ult) without taking any chances (Since it's only 30 seconds at most until you're able to suit up again).

To that end, here are the key points:

1. Try not to lose your mech when surrounded by the enemy team. Easier said than done, I know, but D.Va has great mobility. Try to make your mech last as long as possible by intelligently using her defense matrix.
2. You're vulnerable WHILE suiting up. Don't suit up in the open or in the middle of a fire fight.
3. Conversely, she has brief invulnerability when losing her mech. Try to get away ASAP.

She's a tricky hero, but she has a ton of control over when she engages and how she mitigates damage. You can extend her Mech's life and play conservatively (but not timidly) as a pilot to get back into your Mech.

Comment: Keep in mind that if her mech lands on an enemy while you are suiting up, it will kill them. : )

Comment: @JamesCW It will deal 50 damage.

Comment: +1, want to emphasize that D.Va's mobility is massively enhanced by her jets. You can just look straight up and fly out of a sticky situation. That pistol actually does decent damage, and is super accurate. Anytime I see a Roadhog or Reihhardt, that's pretty much a free new mech in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @Danmaku Good to know, I must have been at low health when it happened to me.

Comment: @DCShannon Completely agree, and her pistol is surprisingly spunky, there are matches where I've made more kills with it than with the mech (even out of the suit she's pretty fast and a much smaller/harder target to hit)

Comment: "...play conservatively as a pilot to..." To what? Don't leave us hanging!

Comment: Just to add something - D.VA is a harassment character, one should never have to ease up on the pressure. While she's in the suit, it's all "in your face" harassment, when you lose the suit it's useful to apply pressure to the enemy team by shooting from a distance or flanking.

Answer (score 8):

D.Va's pistol is pretty decent, so if you're good at getting kills with Mercy you should be able to get kills with D.Va mechless. Worth remembering that both D.Va and Mercy's pistols are fully automatic, you can just hold down the fire button.

The question you have to ask is which is better in any given situation, putting shots downrange to disrupt the opposition, or wasting ~10 seconds + the run back to respawn with more firepower.

Comment: yea, her pistol does quite a bit of damage.

Comment: Wikia says 14 per round at 7 rounds a second. Ouch

Answer (score 5):

She's not so bad by herself.

D'va does stand a chance against lower HP non Tank heroes. My Hanzo has been killed by a non mech D'va more than once. I wouldn't kill myself, handicapping my team and giving the enemy free ult charge. Instead hide behind your tanks and wait for your own ult to reach 100% and get your mehc back.